# Cannot query WebSQL in Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, jquery-mobile, web-sql

When I use normal query (which works on browser) in Android using this code:

```
var sql = 'SELECT DPHID FROM DPH';
var sqlParam = [];

db.transaction(
    function queryDB(tx) {
        tx.executeSql(sql, sqlParam, 
            function querySuccess(tx, results) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(results.rows));
                ... call other function ...
            }
        , error);
    }
, error);

function error(tx, err) {
    console.log("Error");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(tx));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
}
```

It only prints this for success (without the result data):

> {"length":5} at null:339

but it prints outer error:

> {"code":0,"message":"the statement callback raised an exception or
>   statement error callback did not return false"} at null:615

What could be wrong?

Comment: With what version of android are you testing this?

Comment: Tried it in emulator 4.1.1 and my phone 4.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally SOLVED it!

I try to explain what I can learn:

The error happens because I use the `results` in other function which I call like this:

```
results.rows[0]
```

This works flawless in PC browser, but not in Android mobile application. I need to use this:

```
results.rows.item(0)
```

to get the object from `results`.

What I still don't understand is when I print `results.rows`, it only prints `{"length":5} at null:339` that made me suspected that there is something wrong in my code (which I have tested in PC browser without problem).